# how to check mark all the names in tableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am displaying an array with names in tableview.

selected row will be indicated with check,and finely i am getting selected names into a list.

my code for that is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.sourceArray count];;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if ([self.selectedArray containsObject:[agentemails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self.selectedArray containsObject:[agentemails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        [self.selectedArray removeObjectAtIndex:[self.selectedArray indexOfObject:[agentemails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.selectedArray addObject:[agentemails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

now i need to place a button select-all when ever use click on it i need to check all the names in the table how can i done can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a BOOL in your header, then doing this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    myBoolean = YES;
    [tableView reloadData];
    myBoolean = NO;
}
```

Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, just add this:

```
if(myBoolean){
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

Comment: Thank u Aurum Aquila,if i use this code by clicking select all button all the table rows will be selected,But again when i select on selected row to uncheck it will not,all are in checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender
{
    if(myBoolean)
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
                [[self.iTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            }
        }

        myBoolean = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.iTable.numberOfSections; s++)
        {
            for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.iTable numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
            {
                [[self.iTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
            }
        }

        myBoolean = YES;
    }
}
```